# How to view weight assigned to each observation in survey package?

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to create and view weights for each observation using the `survey` package. I have data of the form (simplified example):

```
# Create data

set.seed(12345)
preYear = c(0:100)
preYear = sample(preYear, 100, replace = TRUE)

income = c(0:100000)
income = sample(income, 100, replace = TRUE)

gender = c("Male", "Female")
gender = sample(gender, 100, replace = TRUE)
gender = as.numeric(factor(gender))

ethnicity = c("White", "African_American", "Mixed_Ethnicity", "Other_Ethnicity")
ethnicity = sample(ethnicity, 100, replace = TRUE)
ethnicity = as.numeric(factor(ethnicity))

postYear = preYear + 10

data = cbind(preYear, income, gender, ethnicity, postYear)
data = as.data.frame(data)
```

Using the survey package I weight on gender:

```
library(survey)
data.svy.unweighted <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=data)

#
gender.dist <- data.frame(gender = c("1", "2"),
                          Freq = nrow(data) * c(0.45, 0.55))

data.svy.rake <- rake(design = data.svy.unweighted,
                      sample.margins = list(~gender),
                      population.margins = list(gender.dist))

data.svy.rake

Independent Sampling design (with replacement)
rake(design = data.svy.unweighted, sample.margins = list(~gender), 
    population.margins = list(gender.dist))
```

However, I don't know how to view the vector of weights. Ideally, what I would like is to be able to return a data.table that is identical to `data` but has an additional column called `weight` which corresponds to the weight assigned to each observation after weighting on gender. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, are you looking for one of the attributes (or its inverse) that print to the screen when you run `str(data.svy.rake)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the weights from a survey design object in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73627746/how-do-i-get-the-weights-from-a-survey-design-object-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

The `weights()` function returns the weights of a survey design object.  The `model.frame()` function returns the variables, so you can just combine the two.

Comment: This appears to work! Thank you!

Comment: This is what's done by the function [`as_data_frame_with_weights()` from the 'svrep' package.](https://bschneidr.github.io/svrep/reference/as_data_frame_with_weights.html), which handles both full-sample and replicate weights.